# KeyPress to detect 'Enter' blocks any data entry on an Input text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Beginner with React and I am bumping into an issue. I have a profile page where the user can change each field (First name, Email, etc.) and once 'Enter' is pressed, it saves that particular field (redux/axios/promise).

The problem I have is that when I use onKeyPress/Down/Up as event trigger, it blocks any data entry. Meaning, i cannot type anything in the field, as if it was read-only or blocked. If I use onChange, it works.

```
class Account extends Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {

        if( e.key == 'Enter' ) { // this is detected (i console.logged it)

            e.preventDefault(); // also tried without these
            e.stopPropagation(); // also tried without these

            // this is triggered but the text field doesn't change so it updates nothing
            this.props.setUserKvPair( e.target.name, e.target.value );
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="app-account row">

                <div className="component-container col-12">
                    <div className="inner">

                        <p className="form-group">
                            <label className="form-text text-muted">Email Address</label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name="email"
                                className="form-control" 
                                value={this.props.user.email} 
                                onKeyDown={this.handleChange} />
                        </p>
                        <p className="form-group">
                            <label className="form-text text-muted">First Name</label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name="first_name"
                                className="form-control" 
                                value={this.props.user.first_name} 
                                onKeyPress={this.handleChange} />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
    return {
        user: state.user.data,
        properties: state.properties.data,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch);
}


export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(Account);
```

Basically, everything works but it's just that the value of the text input doesn't change unless I use onChange.

How can I remove that blockage/readonly on the field?

Comment: perhaps you could use a form to do this and then hook the `onSubmit` event and call `event.preventDefault()` method.  Then you would get the press enter functionality for free.  Also, I typically recommend using controlled components for inputs. I will post a sample snippet of code shortly to coincide with what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a form for this as it grants free `onEnter` functionality without having to wire up a bunch of different event handlers. Also, I suggest using [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) which does make use of the `onChange` handler but caches all input values in the component state. This makes using the data extremely easy.

See below code for an example

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            text_1: "",
            text_2: ""
        };

        this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
    }

    submitHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { text_1, text_2 } = this.state;

        console.log(text_1, text_2);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // Using a form gives free on 'Enter' functionality
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                {/* Controlled Component 1 */}
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.text_1}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ text_1: e.target.value })}
                />

                {/* Controlled Component 2 */}
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.text_2}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ text_2: e.target.value })}
                />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, it's impossible to have the user enter some text, check on onKeyPress if it's enter, and if it is, allow that the handling function to trigger a save just for this field?

Comment: thats possible but i strongly recommend the use of `controlled components` to do so.  As the other post mentioned, you cannot use the `value={this.props.user.email}` without `onChange`.

Comment: can I capture the last key pressed with onChange? if so, i can make an if statement and ignore all keys but Enter?

Comment: Im unsure about that. Again, I recommend taking advantage of the built in browser support that a form offers.

Comment: What approach did you end up going with?

Answer (score 1):

How can you write something in the input with a `value` and without `onChange`?

`value={this.props.user.email}` without `onChange` this mean your input is read only

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/84207/

Comment: This value `{this.props.user.email}` is the existing state (fetched from the DB/API), and by typing in it the user can change and type enter to save that field.

Not sure what's coming across as Read Only here? There is subtlety I must miss.

Comment: If you want to use the enter key with an initial value of the input you need to use both onChange and onKeyPress, chek the fiddle, I've attached.